# Access DoCmd print method

Tags: ms-access, printing

I'm selecting some record and I have option to view them as a report (by pushing Command33 button)

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "repAwariaOtwarta", acViewPreview, , "[dbAwarieOtwarte].[ID] =" & Me![ID]
End Sub
```

After clicking the button I have report pop up.
What I should do to print that report without overwiewing it after clicking Command33?

I was trying to use DoCmd.PrintOut, but I seem to failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine your ideas:
Open the report, use the print command.

```
 Private Sub Command33_Click()
       DoCmd.OpenReport "repAwariaOtwarta", acViewPreview, , _
                  "[dbAwarieOtwarte].[ID] =" & Me![ID]
       DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , 1
 End Sub
```

Here are the paramteres for Printout command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192667.aspx

If you want, you can do a close method for the report after the print commmand like

`DoCmd.Close acReport, "repAwariaOtwarta"`